# Why does a for-loop terminate when the middle parameter is 'null'?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am a beginner at javascript.

I have a question about the one of the 'hints' in the "A List" exercise problem from [eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net//04_data.html):

let's say I'm looping through the following list in the body of a function called listToArray:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

The hint recommends using the following loop: `for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {}`

The explanation is as follows:

> Can you see how that works? Every iteration of the loop, node points to the current sublist, and the body can read its value property to get the current element. At the end of an iteration, node moves to the next sublist. When that is null, we have reached the end of the list and the loop is finished.

What I would like to know is: **why don't we need to write `node === null` as the middle parameter like in every other for loop i've ever seen in my life?**

**UPDATE:** I understand that 'null' is falsy.  To reiterate the question, perhaps more succinclty: why don't we need the comparison operator ('===') to terminate the loop?

Comment: You don't have to write `node == null` in C or C++. In this respect, JavaScript is similar to those languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is falsy in js, so the condition evaluates to false, terminating the for loop. Comparison operators return booleans. You don't need a comparison operator, because you already have a boolean(ish) term.

Answer (score 2):

The test expression of a `for` loop can be *any expression whatsoever*.  It's evaluated as a Boolean, but it doesn't have to be a comparison.

There is nothing special about comparison syntax.  `x == y` is just an expression, the same as `1+2` or `myfunc(blah)`.  In this case, the value of the expression isn't a number, but a Boolean: `true` if `x` is "equal" to `y` (under `==` rules), and `false` otherwise.

(You can use comparisons anywhere else you use an expression, too; for instance:

```
does_x_equal_y = (x == y)
```

will set the variable `does_x_equal_y` to either `true` or `false`.)

When an arbitrary, non-comparison expression is evaluated, there are many possibilities for its value besides `true` and `false`. But in a Boolean context like the test in a `for` loop, all those possibilities get interpreted as equivalent to one or the other.  We call non-Boolean values that are interpreted as true "truthy", and those that are interpreted as false "falsy", to distinguish them from the actual Boolean values `true` and `false`.

In Javascript,`null` and `undefined` and 0 and the empty string (and a few other things) are falsy, but everything else is truthy.  So if `node.next` references an object, it will be truthy, and the loop will continue; if it is undefined/null, it will be falsy, and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 0):

To explain further, one good way to find falsey values in JavaScript is to open up Console and type:

```
null ? true : false
```

For the most part these values are intuitive.